# Linux, BlueZ, Initiating an hid BlueTooth Connection

Tags: linux, bluetooth, hid, bluez

### Use-case

- Ubuntu machine is simulating a Keyboard
- Ubuntu machine ( the virtual keyboard ) imitates a connection to the remote device to be controlled

### Question

In normal scenario, the HID Desc is reported through SDP, and thus, when the device connects to the keyboard it already knows the HID Desc to be used, in my use-case, the Virtual Keyboard ( Ubuntu machine ) initiate the connection, and thus, it's not triggered using SDP, Having that said, how should I send the device the HIDReport descriptor to be used? is it possible, at-all, to connect a keyboard to a device in this manner? Can I push the HID Report Desc to the Device ( to be controlled ) ?

### Implementation

1. Pair the device with the Ubuntu machine ( done manually )
2. Initiate L2CAP connection on PSMs 0x11 & 0x13
3. Handshake

All is working good so far, this is the point when I would expect to report the HID Descriptor to the device, but how exactly should this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, the HID host only reads the service descriptor once. Afterwards, you can initiate the connection yourself but you must conform to what you have previously told the host via SDP.

I have not come across a way to push the information to HID host later.

If you need to change something, you must clear the host's memory of the device ("uninstall device" in Windows, for an example) and reconnect (host initiating the connection), reading new information from updated SDP records.

If you don't need to change the HID descriptors, I believe you don't need to even have sdpd running after the initial connection. Ever.

Comment: Using the HID boot protocol, can i avoid using SDP all-together? Having pairing done, can i connect from the keyboard to the host directly? ( w/o SDP )?

Comment: I don't think you can. The SDP is needed to deliver other information, such as L2CAP port numbers to use and whether the device even supports boot protocol. Of course you may try to connect to some default ports and see whether the host is even listening on those.